# form submit - php ajax jquery-ui - will not execute on Firefox or IE

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a drop down form, which has a list of four choices the user can select from. After selecting the choice
and clicking the "Advertise in Public Chat" button the option value (1, 2, 3, 4) needs to be passed to advertise.php?advertise=1 (2, 3, or 4)
without the page refreshing. After clicking Advertise in Public Chat I would like a message that says "Message sent to Chat!" and the user can click OK.

**My issue:**

Code will not execute on Firefox or Internet Explorer (I have tried on Debian Linux & Windows PCs-- all share the same result). Works perfectly on Chrome\Opera.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" action="" method="post">
            <select name="Type">
                <option value="1">(1 on 1)</option>
                <option value="2">(2 on 2)</option>
                <option value="3">(3 on 3)</option>
                <option value="4">(4 on 4)</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Advertise in Public Chat">
        </form>
        <div id="message"><h2>This will change when the request is sent</h2></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(event) {
              $('form').on('submit', function(){
                  event.preventDefault();        
                  var myVal = $('select[name="Type"]').val();
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "advertise.php",
                    data: {
                        advertise: myVal
                    }
                  }).done(function( response ) {
                    // response is equal to what advertise.php will echo/print
                    $('#message h2').html("Message sent to Chat!");
                      });
              });
          });
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you -submit- a form, the page will be refreshed. You have to stop or prevent default action for the submit event of your form. Here is a example using jquery:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your ajax function
});
```

Comment: Alright well this is one of the many issues I'm having in the example above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
<input type="submit" value="Advertise in Public Chat">
```

You can use

```
<input type="button" id="submit-btn" value="Advertise in Public Chat">
```

and for the ajax you can do like this:

```
$("#submit-btn").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "advertise.php",
   data: dataString,
   success: function() {
    $('#message').html("<h2>Message sent to Chat!</h2>")
   }
  });
});
});
```

Comment: When I click the button the page refreshes and I don't see "Message sent to Chat. I have the jquery ui library and then the script following it in between the head tag. Any idea why jquery isn't loading?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: If you use firebug then please check what you get in response. And as per you code you have not taken any element with id `message`, so it may possible that the ajax call was successful but as there is no element with the id `message`, you are not getting you message. I made this demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/DDnyV/2/), hope this will help you. The php code is in the fiddle comment.

Answer (score 0):

Like that you will be able to access $_GET['advertise'] in advertise.php

**UPDATE**

I forgot to put the curly braces in the data declaration in the first time, now it will work

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();        
        var myVal = $('select[name="Type"]').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "advertise.php",
          data: {
              advertise: myVal
          },
          success: function() {
            $('#message').html("<h2>Message sent to Chat!</h2>");
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**UPDATE 2**
I just tested this in local and it works assuming that advertise.php is at the same level as this file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" action="" method="post">
            <select name="Type">
                <option value="1">(1 on 1)</option>
                <option value="2">(2 on 2)</option>
                <option value="3">(3 on 3)</option>
                <option value="4">(4 on 4)</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Advertise in Public Chat">
        </form>
        <div id="message"><h2>This will change when the request is sent</h2></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('form').on('submit', function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();        
                  var myVal = $('select[name="Type"]').val();
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "advertise.php",
                    data: {
                        advertise: myVal
                    }
                  }).done(function( response ) {
                    // response is equal to what advertise.php will echo/print
                    $('#message h2').html("Message sent to Chat!");
                      });
              });
          });
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When I click the button the page refreshes and I don't see "Message sent to Chat. I have the jquery ui library and then the script following it in between the head tag. Any idea why jquery isn't loading?

Comment: I think there is an issue is worth the form . The page is still refreshing and I'm not seeing Message sent to Chat.

Comment: Updated with full html and js, this works just fine for me in local

Comment: I have tried on 3 different computers (linux debian\windows) and it only executes on Chrome\Opera (for both). I don't even think jquery is loading on FF\IE as nothing happens after I submit. Is this jquery related?

Comment: Try changing `$('form').on('submit', function(){` for `$('form').on('submit', function(event){`

Comment: Still nothing, but it remains functional in chrome\opera.

Comment: I can't really help then :S on my macbook it works perfectly in FF and chrome

Comment: i figured it out the issue was Ad Block Plus or Pro... why i have no idea.. but when enabled i can't use the script

Comment: I only have it installed on chrome and I don't get the issue so I couldn't tell, but it seems like there is some issue from it blocking scripts based on their name. Does everything works when adblock is disabled?

Comment: Yes adblock was the only issue